# concurrent requests to Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I am using python-ldap to connect to a remote Active Directory.
Is there a way to find out/ tweak the number of concurrent connections supported by Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

[According to this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315071), the limits are specified in `cn=Query-Policies,cn=Directory Service,cn=Windows NT,cn=Services` of the configuration root. The property for concurrent connections is `MaxConnections`. However, the limit is per DC and, by default, is set to 5000. I'd be very suspicious that your application requires more connections than that.

Comment: Does the MaxConnection count apply when a connection is being made to retrieve the objectGUID after retrieving the distinguishedName of a group member? Does that count as 1 concurrent connection while the loop runs, or 1 connection for each loop iteration? For context, see the question I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158375/active-directory-tune-performance-of-function-to-retrieve-group-members#50159468

Comment: @JWeezy: That's really dependent on the implementation of the `DirectorySearcher` and `DirectoryEntry` classes in .NET, which I am not familiar with. You might have better luck asking this as a separate question.